# Codes inside fillOval() method?

Tags: java, methods

Is there a way I can see the code in fillOval() method (just to see how they code it that efficent)?

I tried to write my own method for drawing a circle and come up with two different methods for it. However non of them could prpcessed as fast as the original fillOval() method. (mines take to draw near 200~400 milisecond, original method takes just 0!) And this make me think about what can the code in the method may be ,but I can't find it on the web (I think it is private to the company (Oracle)..?).

Comment: The code falls through to the native code and will based on the particular implementation of the JVM and the target platform.  Most try and use OpenGL or DirectX.  Have a look at the source code for Java 8